# Barycentric subdivision definition confusion

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

From page 114 of Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

> If $X$ is a space, then the $n$-th Barycentric Subdivision is defined as the homomorphism $Sd_n : S_n(X) \rightarrow S_n(X)$ defined on generators $\Delta^n \rightarrow X$ by $Sd_n(\sigma) = \sigma_\text{#}Sd_n(\delta^n)$, where $\sigma_{\text{#}} : S_n(\Delta^n) \rightarrow S_n(X)$ and $\delta^n: \Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^n$ is the identity mapping.

I don't understand how this mapping works, it almost seems like it's just the identity map.  If $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are two arbitrary generators of $X$, then $Sd_n(\sigma_1) = (\sigma_1)_{\text{#}}Sd_n(\delta^n)$ and $Sd_n(\sigma_2) = (\sigma_2)_{\text{#}}Sd_n(\delta^n)$.  But if $\delta^n : \Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^n$ is the identity map and both $\sigma_{1,2} : \Delta^n \rightarrow X$, then wouldn't they both map to the same element of $S_n(X)$?

Comment: What's a reference for where you have taken the definition from?

Comment: I've added it in, it's Rotman's Algebraic Topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you substitute $\sigma=\sigma_1$ into the formula 
$$Sd_n(\sigma)=\sigma_\#(Sd_n(\delta^n))
$$
you get 
$$Sd_n(\sigma_1)=(\sigma_1)_\#(Sd_n(\delta^n))
$$ 
not 
$$Sd_n(\sigma_1)=\sigma_\#(Sd_n(\delta^n))
$$

Comment: Whoops, notation error.  But what's the difference between $(\sigma_1)_{\text{#}}(Sd_n(\delta^n))$ and $(\sigma_2)_{\text{#}}(Sd_n(\delta^n))$?

Comment: $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 : \Delta \to X$ can be entirely different functions. So you would expect their induced chain maps $$(\sigma_1)_\#,(\sigma_2)_\# : S_n(\Delta) \to S_n(X)$$ to be entirely different.